# VueJs 2: How to display prop in another component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a simple question, but cannot find how to solve.

There are 2 Vue 2 Components. In Component 1, two props are passed, which therefore are used in Component 2.

```
// Component 1
Vue.component('component1', {
    props: {
        titleTest: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        textTest: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    },
    template: `
    <div>
        <div :title="titleTest">{{ titleTest }}</div>
        <div :data-test="textTest">{{ textTest }}</div>
    </div>
    `,
    created() {
        console.log('Created1');
        this.$root.$refs.component1 = this;
    },
    methods: {
        foo: function() {
            alert('this is component1.foo');
        }
    }
});

// Component 2
Vue.component('component2', {
    template: `
    <div>
        <div>Some text</div>
        <ul>
            <li>List Item1</li>
            <li>List Item2</li>
        </ul>
        <div>
            <button id='test' type="submit" @click="bar">Text</button>
            <component1 ref="component1" :title="test1" :data-test="test2"></component1>
        </div>
    </div>
    `,
    data: function() {
        return {
            test1: 'testText1',
            test2: 'testText2'
        };
    },
    methods: {
        bar: function() {
            this.$root.$refs.component1.foo();
        }
    },
    created: function() {
        console.log('Created2');
    }
});

new Vue({
    el: '#plotlyExample',
});
```

My idea, when I use Component 1 in Component 2 HTML template and bind data variables, they should be displayed. However, Vue sets only "title" and "data-test" but {{ titleTest }}, {{ textTest }} are not displayed. Additionally Vue sets props in one div, instead of two separate.

[image: Screenshot]

My ideal result is:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You named your props `titleTest` and `textTest`, that means you need to pass `title-test` and `text-test`, **NOT** `title` and `data-test`.

The reason they end up in your main `<div>` is because when Vue doesn't recognise them as props (because you used different names), it falls back on assuming they're regular HTML attributes (like `class`, `id`, and `style`)

In order for it to work, you either need to rename your props to `title` and `dataTest` in Component1, or you should use the `title-test` and `text-test` names in Component2.

Answer (score 1):

You just need pass props to the `component1`

```
<component1 ref="component1" :title-test="test1" :text-test="test2"></component1>
```

Answer (score 1):

you are missnaming the props in the component1 ( child component ) , you used `title` and `data-test` but your props names are titleTest and textTest ! so you should use `title-test` and `text-test` instead .

**:prop-name="propValue"**